# python pip install not working, failed with error code 1

Tags: python, pip, installation

Nothing ive tried has worked and nothing ive found online has worked, including upgrading setuptools and a couple other things as well as installing visual studio. Heres what I get back, minus some because stackoverflow doesnt like it.

```
C:\Users\ejhsc>py -m pip install pandas
```

Collecting pandas

```
#ifndef _NPY_NPY_CONFIG_H_
#error config.h should never be included directly, include npy_config.h instead
#endif

EOF
_configtest.c
_configtest.c(6): fatal error C1189: #error:  gcc >= 4 required
File: build\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\include/numpy\_numpyconfig.h
#define NPY_SIZEOF_SHORT SIZEOF_SHORT
#define NPY_SIZEOF_INT SIZEOF_INT
#define NPY_SIZEOF_LONG SIZEOF_LONG
#define NPY_SIZEOF_FLOAT 4
#define NPY_SIZEOF_COMPLEX_FLOAT 8
#define NPY_SIZEOF_DOUBLE 8
#define NPY_SIZEOF_COMPLEX_DOUBLE 16
#define NPY_SIZEOF_LONGDOUBLE 8
#define NPY_SIZEOF_COMPLEX_LONGDOUBLE 16
#define NPY_SIZEOF_PY_INTPTR_T 8
#define NPY_SIZEOF_OFF_T 4
#define NPY_SIZEOF_PY_LONG_LONG 8
#define NPY_SIZEOF_LONGLONG 8
#define NPY_NO_SIGNAL 1
#define NPY_NO_SMP 0
#define NPY_HAVE_DECL_ISNAN
#define NPY_HAVE_DECL_ISINF
#define NPY_HAVE_DECL_SIGNBIT
#define NPY_HAVE_DECL_ISFINITE
#define NPY_USE_C99_COMPLEX 1
#define NPY_RELAXED_STRIDES_CHECKING 1
#define NPY_USE_C99_FORMATS 1
#define NPY_VISIBILITY_HIDDEN
#define NPY_ABI_VERSION 0x01000009
#define NPY_API_VERSION 0x0000000C

#ifndef __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS 1
#endif

EOF
### Warning:  Using unoptimized lapack ###
### Warning:  Using unoptimized lapack ###
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.swp' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.bak' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\pep425tags.py:89: RuntimeWarning: Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
  warn=(impl == 'cp')):
C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\pep425tags.py:93: RuntimeWarning: Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
  warn=(impl == 'cp')):
Running from numpy source directory.
C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-kqath4mp\numpy-1.14.2\setup.py:369: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
  run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-kqath4mp\numpy-1.14.2\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-kqath4mp\numpy-1.14.2\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-kqath4mp\numpy-1.14.2\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-kqath4mp\numpy-1.14.2\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-kqath4mp\numpy-1.14.2\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
  warnings.warn(msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 423, in compile
    self.spawn(args)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 542, in spawn
    return super().spawn(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-kqath4mp\numpy-1.14.2\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 89, in <lambda>
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-kqath4mp\numpy-1.14.2\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 152, in CCompiler_spawn
distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: Command "G:\Program Files (x86)\visual studio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DNPY_NEEDS_MINGW_TIME_WORKAROUND -Inumpy\core\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\include/numpy -Inumpy\core\src\private -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -IC:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -IC:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\private -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\private -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\private -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\npymath -I"G:\Program Files (x86)\visual studio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\ATLMFC\include" -I"G:\Program Files (x86)\visual studio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\cppwinrt" /Tcnumpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.obj" failed with exit status 2

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 172, in run
    cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 158, in call_command
    self.run_command(cmdname)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 11, in run
    self.build()
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 107, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-kqath4mp\numpy-1.14.2\numpy\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 262, in run
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
    self._build_extensions_serial()
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-kqath4mp\numpy-1.14.2\numpy\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 370, in build_extension
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 425, in compile
    raise CompileError(msg)
distutils.errors.CompileError: Command "G:\Program Files (x86)\visual studio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DNPY_NEEDS_MINGW_TIME_WORKAROUND -Inumpy\core\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\include/numpy -Inumpy\core\src\private -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -IC:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -IC:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\private -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\private -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\private -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\npymath -I"G:\Program Files (x86)\visual studio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\ATLMFC\include" -I"G:\Program Files (x86)\visual studio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\cppwinrt" /Tcnumpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.obj" failed with exit status 2

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-kqath4mp\numpy-1.14.2\setup.py", line 394, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-kqath4mp\numpy-1.14.2\setup.py", line 386, in setup_package

  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-kqath4mp\numpy-1.14.2\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 129, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
    raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
SystemExit: error: Command "G:\Program Files (x86)\visual studio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DNPY_NEEDS_MINGW_TIME_WORKAROUND -Inumpy\core\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\include/numpy -Inumpy\core\src\private -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -IC:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -IC:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\private -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\private -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\private -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\npymath -I"G:\Program Files (x86)\visual studio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\ATLMFC\include" -I"G:\Program Files (x86)\visual studio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\cppwinrt" /Tcnumpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.obj" failed with exit status 2

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1138, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
    raise
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
    saved_exc.resume()
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
    six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-kqath4mp\numpy-1.14.2\setup.py", line 394, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-kqath4mp\numpy-1.14.2\setup.py", line 386, in setup_package

  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-kqath4mp\numpy-1.14.2\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 129, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
    raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
SystemExit: error: Command "G:\Program Files (x86)\visual studio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DNPY_NEEDS_MINGW_TIME_WORKAROUND -Inumpy\core\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\include/numpy -Inumpy\core\src\private -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -IC:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -IC:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\private -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\private -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\private -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\npymath -I"G:\Program Files (x86)\visual studio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\ATLMFC\include" -I"G:\Program Files (x86)\visual studio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\cppwinrt" /Tcnumpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.obj" failed with exit status 2

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-1e4hbexj\pandas\setup.py", line 743, in <module>
    **setuptools_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 128, in setup
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 123, in _install_setup_requires
    dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 513, in fetch_build_eggs
    replace_conflicting=True,
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 774, in resolve
    replace_conflicting=replace_conflictingmtrand.c
numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(38704): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'long', possible loss of data
numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(38714): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'long', possible loss of data
numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(38781): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'long', possible loss of data
numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(40158): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'unsigned long', possible loss of data
numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(40348): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'unsigned long', possible loss of data
numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(40514): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'unsigned long', possible loss of data
numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(43536): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(45472): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\users\ejhsc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(205): note: see declaration of '_ts'
numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(45473): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\users\ejhsc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(205): note: see declaration of '_ts'
numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(45474): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\users\ejhsc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(205): note: see declaration of '_ts'
numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(45481): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\users\ejhsc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(205): note: see declaration of '_ts'
numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(45482): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\users\ejhsc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(205): note: see declaration of '_ts'
numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(45483): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\users\ejhsc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(205): note: see declaration of '_ts'
numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(45484): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\users\ejhsc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(205): note: see declaration of '_ts'
numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(45485): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\users\ejhsc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(205): note: see declaration of '_ts'
numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(45486): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\users\ejhsc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(205): note: see declaration of '_ts'
numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(45541): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\users\ejhsc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(205): note: see declaration of '_ts'
numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(45542): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\users\ejhsc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(205): note: see declaration of '_ts'
numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(45543): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\users\ejhsc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(205): note: see declaration of '_ts'
numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(45544): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\users\ejhsc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(205): note: see declaration of '_ts'
numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(45545): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\users\ejhsc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(205): note: see declaration of '_ts'
numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c(45546): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
c:\users\ejhsc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(205): note: see declaration of '_ts'

  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1057, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1069, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 580, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 673, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 699, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 884, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1152, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1140, in run_setup
    raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Command "G:\Program Files (x86)\visual studio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DNPY_NEEDS_MINGW_TIME_WORKAROUND -Inumpy\core\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\include/numpy -Inumpy\core\src\private -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -IC:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -IC:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\private -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\private -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\npymath -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\private -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\core\src\npymath -I"G:\Program Files (x86)\visual studio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\ATLMFC\include" -I"G:\Program Files (x86)\visual studio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\cppwinrt" /Tcnumpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.obj" failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ejhsc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-1e4hbexj\pandas\

Comment: In order to run this command you must have `pythonpy` in your system. Also, if you want to install pandas in your system `pip install pandas` also works pretty well.

Comment: At first you should check that you have the latest version of `pip` installed. And also be aware that Python 3.7 is not released yet. You should use 3.6 for now.

Comment: I see now that it does seem to say something about build 3.7 but I'm not sure why it would, I should be on 3.6.4, the one thats live on website. Maybe not... And pip is updated as well. I updated everything that I found online that it suggested to update so maybe it is python needing a downgrade.
Also, i never got just pip install whatever to work, i either used the full path or py -m pip install, should that matter?
Or could it also be pandas is trying to install for 3.7??

Comment: Don't expect all packages to work on 3.7 already.

Comment: Im not, at all, just wondering how I ended up with 3.7, like I said I should be on 3.6.4.. I even reinstalled python this morning before work and it still gave the same error.

Comment: Im still confused on how I ended up with python 3.7... But I checked and sure enough thats the version it was trying to use.. But then I still had 3.6.4 and 3.6.2 installed as well.